# python selenium - picking the right option with the right name

Tags: python, selenium

https://gyazo.com/b3e792b66775f64147671a6f23bd52c7

On the picture out from the first red dot, is there a list of options if u click on the "vælg" button (its in my language). I want my script to click on the right option.
Lets say the right one is "unisexur." How do I make my script click the option that says "unisexur" in the option list.

I know how to choose one of the options by e.g. xpath:

```
choice = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="matrix-element-666"]/option[2]')
sleep(1)
choice.click()
```

which will make the code take the second option. So that is not what I want.
The html code is in the picture in the top..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`select_by_value`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=select_by_value#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_value).

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('matrix-element-666'))
select.select_by_value('unisexur').click()
```